# RequestError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, node.js

I am new to Microsoft SQL Server, please advise.

I am receiving the following error message when I deploy code into my development environment (which is hosted on Azure using Node.js (version 10) and Objection.js (1.4.0). It works fine locally and only seems to have issues with specific queries on the development environment.

#### Error Details

> ```
> RequestError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET 
>     at handleError (/src/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:519:15) 
>     at Connection.emit (events.js:203:15) 
>     at Connection.socketError (/src/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1028:14) 
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (/src/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:878:18) 
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15) 
>     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8) 
>     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3) 
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
> ```

#### Code

```
 return Order.query()
.joinEager('[shipments.shipmentQuantities.lineItem, lineItems.shipmentQuantities]')
.findById(id);
```

### Connection File

```
database: {
  client: 'mssql',
  connection: {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    charset: 'utf8',
    stream: true,
       options: process.env.ENABLE_DB_SSL ? {
       port: 1433,
       database: process.env.DB_NAME,
       encrypt: true,
    } : undefined,
   },
    debug: false,
  },
```

Answer (score -4):

try adding packetsize as an option

Comment: How and why to do so would make this a better answer.